# NetConnection will drop after 4 streams were viewed

Tags: actionscript-3, air, stream, netconnection

In my Adobe AIR application I have a list of video streams available to view, user can switch from stream to stream, however `NetConnection` will raise `NetConnection.Connect.Closed` event after user switched between 4 streams, basic example

```
User connects to stream1 -> works
User switches to stream2 -> works
User switches to stream3 -> works
User switches to stream4 -> works
User switches back to stream1 -> NetConnection.Connect.Closed raised
```

I am wondering what is this magic number 4 ?
So far I have checked the following things but nothing worked:

1. Changed number of `maxPeerConnections` on `NetConnection` ->
   irrelevant
2. Changed number of processes on my video server -> 
   irrelevant

So the only solution for me right now is to restart NetConnection every time user has reached 4 stream views limit, but that's not the best solution, obviously.

If anyone can point me on what this magic number is - would be great!

Comment: Maybe it's the fact that you're switching back to a stream it already played? Try connecting to `stream1`, then `stream2`, then back to `stream1` to see if you have the same issue. If so, you may need to perform some operation on `stream1` before it can be reused.

Comment: tried that, not the case. I can switch from stream1 to stream2 and then from stream2 to stream1 up to 4 times, then it throws NetConnection.Connect.Closed